# Python pandas groupby boxplots overlap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm puzzled by this Pandas/Matplotlib behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

series = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
classifier = lambda x: 'Odd' if x%2 else "Even"
grouped = series.groupby(classifier)

grouped.plot(kind='box')
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplots overlap]

How do I get the boxplots next to each other *Pandas style* i.e. with nice syntax? :)

(Pandas v. 0.16.2, Matplotlib v. 1.4.3)

Edit:
I know I could do this:

```
grouped = grouped.apply(pd.Series.to_frame)
```

but I would assume there's a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: is the `seaborn` library an option?

Comment: I'd prefer Matplotlib, since I'm teaching a class and we haven't touched seaborn...

Comment: seaborn's plotting is built off of matplotlib in the same manner as pandas

Comment: Oh, well why not then. :)

Comment: This is not really supported yet, but work is underway to improve this: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8018 (if you want to know the reason: groupby.plot is doing now something similar as looping through the groups and plotting each of them. For dataframes is will create separate figures then, but series are plotted on the same figure, resulting in this wrong figure).

Answer (score 3):

So my general advice is to avoid plotting through pandas with the following exceptions:

1. Super quick 'n' dirty interactive exploration and inspection
2. Time series

Any other time you'll want to use seaborn or roll your own matplotlib function. Since you're working with a dataframe, seaborn is your best bet, although labeled data support is very quickly coming down the pipe for matplotlib.

I'm also going to advise that you go ahead and create the dataframe with the classification stored inside of it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
seaborn.set(style='ticks')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['val'])
df['class'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: 'Odd' if x%2 else "Even")
seaborn.boxplot(x='class', y='val', data=df, width=0.5)
seaborn.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to start using seaborn. For the record, it was enough to say seaborn.boxplot(grouped) in my original example.

Comment: On closer inspection your example plots a DataFrame, whereas I was looking for a solution to nicely plot a SeriesGroupBy object.

Comment: Well it works for this simple case, but groupby is more practical for real and more complex data.